# Kotlin does not allow multiple inheritance. How can I do something equivalent?

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin

```
class MainActivity : YouTubeBaseActivity() ,AppCompatActivity() (error:multiple inheritance)  {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // attaching layout xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val adapter = PagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    val pager = findViewById<View>(R.id.pager) as ViewPager

    pager.adapter = adapter

    // Initializing YouTube player view
    val youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view) as YouTubePlayerView
    youTubePlayerView.initialize("YOUR API KEY",
            object : YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
                override fun onInitializationSuccess(provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider,
                                                     youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer, b: Boolean) {

                    // do any work here to cue video, play video, etc.
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo("5xVh-7ywKpE")
                }

                override fun onInitializationFailure(provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider,
                                                     youTubeInitializationResult: YouTubeInitializationResult) {

                }
            })

}
```

I use `YoutubeView` with `ViewPager` in this application. I'm getting an error because I can't use `AppCompatActivity().supporFragmentManager(error)`.

Kotlin does not support multiple inheritance. How can I do it?

Comment: You can't do multiple inheritances in Kotlin or Java. I don't understand what you're trying to do though. Can you explain it a bit more and post some code?

Comment: You can't. Make YouTubeBaseActivity() extend AppCompatActivity().

Answer (score 2):

You should not extend FragmentManager in your Avtivity. Activity already contains instance of fragmentManager, so you can get it like `getFragmentManager()` and in Kotlin it's just `fragmentManager`